# How can I use brew to install multiple versions of the same program, like vim?

Tags: macos, bash, shell, unix, homebrew

I'm stuck in the position where I need Vim with Python 2 support, and I need Vim with Python 3 support.

I'd like to be able to install them side by side.

Ideally I'd like to be able to call this from the command line, `vimpy2`, `vimpy2`.

I know this may seem overly specific, but there are a few cases where I need the different builds of software to be install with brew.

Comment: I have never tried this myself, but you can just make brew formulae to build apps however you want, and not link the into the `/usr/local` tree, or link them differently. See http://superuser.com/questions/563484/installing-homebrew-packages-without-linking

Comment: Is  brew a generic UNIX thing now? I always associated that with OSX

Comment: @sehe, the unix tag is more about the fixing up the path.

Comment: @Rollo cough. The missing [tag:osx] tag was more about you not getting help that way :) No need to thank me